# Background image slow zoom in

Tags: css, zooming, transform

I have been looking around everywhere but I cannot seem to find a definitive answer on how to make the background image slowly zoom in using CSS. Help would be appreciated. My code so far zooms the text elements but not the background.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center-top;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 5s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get the body to scale as required, my guess is that the user stylesheet is overriding it for some reason. However, as a workaround you could use an inner div like so:

```html
<style>
div {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center-top;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 5s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }

}
</style>
<body>
 <div style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Jaunt, this worked but the image quality seems to go down as it scales in slowly.

Comment: Okay, try different image-rendering properties. An explanation of it can be found at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working example:

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/t8kn1nch/8/)

We basically just use transform: scale; and trigger the change by adding a class with jQuery on an event (I chose to trigger as soon as the DOM loads).

HTML:

```
<main id="kb">
    <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2048-5.jpg" alt="baby elephants" />
</main>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#kb {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#kb img {
    transform-origin: 20% 80%;
    transition: transform 70s linear;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1024px;
    margin-top:-703px;
}
#kb img.zoom {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#kb > img').addClass('zoom');
});
```

If you want to increase or decrease speed just change the value of "transition" in the CSS.

Comment: Looks like you overwrote your example, or the link is bad. Either way, there's no demo there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Fever905/eyag74vn/